# Python API script

Tags: python, api, get

I am making a python script using API of a free test automation website called TestProject.

Link to their API: https://api.testproject.io/docs/v2/

Basically what i want to do is grab pdf of reports of all tests and save them somewhere.

But to make the `GET` request to do that i first need `projectID` and `jobID` which i already wrote functions getting them and saving them in the array.

But now i have a problem where its looping through both lists and not using correct `projectID` and `jobID` and its throwing errors because it does not exist.

So what i need is something to check if `jobID` is in `projectID` so that way i can make a `GET` request to get all the `executionID's` to get the PDF of the report.

I am kinda new to programming so i would love any help i can get. If anyone has any better solutions please feel free to let me know.

My script:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from jsonpath_ng import jsonpath, parse

API_key = 'api_key'
headers = {'Authorization':'{}'.format(API_key)}

list_projectId = []
list_jobId = []
list_executionId = []

ParseData_projectId = parse('$..id')
ParseData_jobId = parse('$..id')
ParseData_executionId = parse('$..id')

def parsing (response,ParseData,list_data):
    # parses data and appends it to the list
    Data = json.loads(response)
    Parsaj = ParseData
    Podatki = Parsaj.find(Data)
            
    for i in range(0, len(Podatki)):
        vrednost = Podatki[i].value
        list_data.append(vrednost)
        
def projectId():
        # gets all projectId's and saves them in list_projectId
        url = 'https://api.testproject.io/v2/projects?_start=0'
                
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        response_json = response.json()
        converted = json.dumps(response_json)
                
        parsing(converted,ParseData_projectId,list_projectId)
                
def jobId():
    # gets all jobId's and saves them in list_jobId
    for i in range(0, len(list_projectId)):
        id = list_projectId[i]
        url = 'https://api.testproject.io/v2/projects/{}'.format(id) + '/jobs?onlyScheduled=false&_start=0'
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        response_json = response.json()
        converted = json.dumps(response_json)
                    
        parsing(converted,ParseData_jobId,list_jobId)
        
def executionId():
    # Their API link:
    # https://api.testproject.io/v2/projects/{projectId}/jobs/{jobId}/reports?_start=0
    # the for loop below does not work here is where i need the help:

    for i in range(0, len(list_projectId)):
        project_id = list_projectId[i]
        job_id = list_jobId[i]
        url = 'https://api.testproject.io/v2/projects/{}'.format(project_id) + '/jobs/{}'.format(job_id) + '/reports?_start=0'
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        response_json = response.json()
        converted = json.dumps(response_json)
        
        parsing(converted,ParseData_executionId,list_executionId)
        


projectId()
print("----------LIST PROJECT ID: ----------")
print(list_projectId)
print("")
jobId()
print("----------LIST JOB ID: ----------")
print(list_jobId)
executionId()
print("----------LIST EXECUTION ID: ----------")
print(list_executionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 'in' operator to check the value exist in the list data structure.

[image]